# How do I find the starting values for a nonlinear model?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

Using RStudio v1.3.1093, R v.4.0.2 on Windows 10.

I working on a homework problem, and given a dataset:

```
x <- cbind(c(8, 8, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 32, 32, 34, 36, 36, 42))
y <- cbind(c(0.49, 0.49, 0.45, 0.43, 0.43, 0.44, 0.43, 0.43, 0.46, 0.45, 0.42, 0.42, 0.43, 0.41, 0.41, 0.40, 0.42, 0.40, 0.40, 0.41, 0.40, 0.41, 0.41, 0.40, 0.40, 0.40, 0.38, 0.41, 0.40, 0.40, 0.41, 0.38, 0.39))

df <- data.frame('x' = x, 'y' = y)
```

We want to fit the model Mitcherlich Law Model: `y = a - b*exp(-c*x) + e` and then discuss how we obtained our starting values.

I used:

```
i <- getInitial(y ~ SSasymp(x, a, b, c), data = df)
```

to get my the starting values, but when I fit the model:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ a - b*exp(-c*x), data = df, start = list(a = i[1], b = i[2], c = i[3]))
```

I get:

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient
> matrix at initial parameter estimates

Am I using the wrong function or is there some other way that I should be calculating the starting values?

Comment: WIth your data, it is working fine for me on R 4.0.3 and Mac Big Sur 10.16 i.e. `getInitial(y ~ SSasymp(x, a, b, c), data = df)#
         a          b          c 
 0.3854869  0.5906224 -2.4551192`

Comment: Those are the values I get as well. But when I use those values to fit the model, that is when I get that error.

Comment: Can you show the code that gives the error so that it can be tested

Comment: I updated the post with the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're probably using the wrong self start function. In a case like this it's possible to plot the points and twiddle with the parameters while plotting the curve that's produced to get close enough for `nls` to work:

```r
x <- cbind(c(8, 8, 14, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20, 20,
             22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 26, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 30, 
             30, 32, 32, 34, 36, 36, 42))

y <- cbind(c(0.49, 0.49, 0.45, 0.43, 0.43, 0.44, 0.43, 0.43, 0.46, 
             0.45, 0.42, 0.42, 0.43, 0.41, 0.41, 0.40, 0.42, 0.40, 
             0.40, 0.41, 0.40, 0.41, 0.41, 0.40, 0.40, 0.40, 0.38, 
             0.41, 0.40, 0.40, 0.41, 0.38, 0.39))

df <- data.frame('x' = x, 'y' = y)

i <- c(a = -0.5, b = -1, c = 0.1)
fit <- nls(y ~ a - b*exp(-c*x), data = df, start = as.list(i))

fit
#> Nonlinear regression model
#>   model: y ~ a - b * exp(-c * x)
#>    data: df
#>        a        b        c 
#>  0.38621 -0.21016  0.09033 
#>  residual sum-of-squares: 0.003971
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.089e-08

plot(df)
lines(5:50, predict(fit, newdata = list(x = 5:50)), col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

If you want something that will approximate the starting points automatcally (and don't want to get into writing a self-start), you can make a few assumptions:

1. Assuming c is positive (i.e. the plot shows a decay like a half-life curve, as your data does), then `exp(-c * x)` will tend to zero with large x, so as long as you have a reasonable range in your data, the minimum value of `y` is likely to be close to `a`
2. If we subtract our y data from the estimated `a`, the value of `b` won't be too far from the intercept of a linear regression through the resulting points.
3. The slope of the regression line created by taking the log of these new y values divided by `b` will be close to -c

So we can create a rough-and-ready estimator for this type of curve like this:

```r
roughstart <- function(x, y) {
    xy <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
    z <- xy[["y"]]
    a <- min(z)
    xy$z <- a - z
    b <- coef(lm(z ~ x, xy))[1]
    xy$z <- log(xy$z/b)
    c <- -coef(lm(z ~ x, xy[is.finite(xy$z),]))[2]
    parms <- as.numeric(c(a, b, c))
    setNames(as.list(parms), c("a", "b", "c"))
}
```

So we can do:

```r
nls(y ~ a - b*exp(-c*x), data = df, start = roughstart(df$x, df$y))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a - b * exp(-c * x)
   data: df
       a        b        c 
 0.38621 -0.21016  0.09033 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.003971

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.616e-06
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Run nls with `SSasymp` and then transform the parameters appropriately giving the answer as in `st` below.  If you want a clean run using exactly your parameterization run nls a second time using the transformed parameters as starting values also shown below.  The second run will have 0 iterations since we are starting at the optimum.

```
fit0 <- nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, R0, lrc), df)
st <- with(as.list(coef(fit0)), c(a = Asym, b = Asym - R0, c = exp(lrc)))
nls(y ~ a - b * exp(-c*x), data = df, start = st)
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a - b * exp(-c * x)
   data: df
       a        b        c 
 0.38621 -0.21016  0.09033 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.003971

Number of iterations to convergence: 0 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.531e-06
```

**2)** As seen there is no problem in running nls with the data in the question but if you do have a problem with different data and want a second option then try the AR.3 model in the drc package.  The code below follows the above code except we make changes to accommodate the different parameterization.

```
library(drc)
fit1 <- drm(y ~ x, data = df, fct = AR.3())
co <- setNames(coef(fit1), c("c", "d", "e"))
st <- with(as.list(co), c(a = d, b = d - c, c = 1/e))
nls(y ~ a - b * exp(-c*x), data = df, start = st)
```

### Update

Have revised.